# Non-last parameter pack compilation error

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, template-argument-deduction

I am trying to understand how parameter packs work in variadic template functions when they are not the last parameter. I don't get why some of my calls in my sample code doesn't work. The questions are in the comments. Should they work or I don't understand something or VS2015 update 3's compiler doesn't support them yet?

```
template <typename T>
double sum(T t) {
    return t;
}

template <typename T, typename... Rest>
double sum(Rest... rest, T t) {
    return t + sum(rest...);
}

template <typename T>
double sum2(T t) {
    return t;
}

template <typename T, typename... Rest>
double sum2(T t, Rest... rest) {
    return t + sum2(rest...);
}

template<typename... Args>
void func(Args..., int = 0)
{}

void func()
{
    func<int, int, int>(1, 1, 1);
    func(1, 1, 1); // why doesn't this compile?
    sum(1, 1); // why doesn't this compile?
    sum<int, int>(1, 1);
    sum<int, int, int>(1, 1, 1); // why doesn't this compile while func<int, int, int>(1, 1, 1) does?

    // why are these compile? I only changed the order of the parameters compared to sum()
    sum2(1);
    sum2(1, 1);
    sum2(1, 1, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really an expert but, as far I know...

```
func(1, 1, 1); // why doesn't this compile?
```

Because, in a function template, the types of a parameter pack can be deduced only if it's in last position.

The first call

```
func<int, int, int>(1, 1, 1);
```

works because the types of the parameter aren't deduced but are explained (`Args...` is `int, int, int`) and `func()` receive a fourth `int` (with default value zero)

The call

```
func<int, int>(1, 1, 1);
```

works also because `Args...` is explained as `int, int` and the `func()` function receive a third `int` with not default value 1

---

```
sum(1, 1); // why doesn't this compile?
```

Same reason: the parameter pack isn't in last position so can't be deduced; but works

```
sum<int, int>(1, 1);
```

because `T` is explicated as `int` and `Rest...` as `int` also.

---

```
sum<int, int, int>(1, 1, 1); // why doesn't this compile while func<int, int, int>(1, 1, 1) does?
```

The fist level call works because `T` is explicated as `int` and `Rest...` as `int, int`; but `sum<int, int, int>(1, 1, 1)` call `sum(rest...)` that, in this case is `sum(1, 1)`; it's `sum(1, 1)` that fail because `Rest...` isn't in last position so can't be deduced

---

```
// why are these compile? I only changed the order of the parameters compared to sum()
sum2(1);
sum2(1, 1);
sum2(1, 1, 1);
```

Because in `sum2()` the parameter pack list `Rest...` is in last position so can be (and is) deduced.